# Match only specific ids in the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to setup the PageNotFound. The 2nd route should match only for ids ['1', '2', '3'];  (these id values hwoever i get after the api call. So i save the values in redux store from inside the Home component). Now when i try and access a incorrect id then it should redirect to PageNotFound. If id in url is lets say 4 it should redirect to PageNotFound.

Do i impletement this is User component when it gets redirected or is there a way to set it up in the below App.js file itself ?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import User from "./Pages/User";
import PageNotFound from "./Pages/PageNotFound";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/user/:id" exact component={User} />
          <Route path="*" exact component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      ;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to do the fetch call inside the App.js? You could have the ids in a state and have your routing based on that

Comment: Just keeping it clean by having just routes there. I just want to know if lets say the id is 4 it would match the 2nd route which is fine, but then there should be extra check to see if 4 is one of the valid ids, if it isnt then i need to redirect to page not found route

Comment: if you dont't want to do the check here, you can also just redirect the user to the pageNotFound path inside the User component

Answer (score 1):

You may create generic component for validation purpose.
Solution should be like this

```
  <Route path="/user/:id" exact component={MyCheckComponent} />
```

MyCheckComponent.jsx

```
const MyCheckComponent =(props) => {
   const {id} = useParams()
   const allowedIds = useSelector(s => s.user.allowedIds)
   return allowedIds.includes(id) ? <User {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/not-found"/>
}
```

At the end you may eliminate MyCheckComponent using render prop of the route.